# Positive operators in $B_2(H)$ (Hilbert Schmidt operators)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

I was reading the paper [Sum of small numbers of idempotents](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.mmj/1028999848) where they have proved that every operator on a Hilbert space can be written as a complex linear combination of 16 projections.  Which also means that positive operators are dense in $B(H)$.

I was wondering if this is true in $B_2(H)$ as well. Does the set $$S=\{T\in B_2(H) : \left<Tx,x\right>\geq 0 ~\forall x\in H\}$$
span whole of $B_2(H)$ in Hilbert Schmidt norm?

Comment: Start with an opetator $A$ that is Hilbert-Schmidt, note that $A+A^*$ and $i(A-A^*)$ are then also Hilbert-Schmidt, and that they are are self-adjoint. The self-adjoints thus span $B_2$. So assume that $A$ is self-adjoint. If you denote with $\chi_{[0,\infty)}$ and $\chi_{(-\infty,0)}$ the characteristic functions of the two intervals $[0,\infty)$, $(-\infty,0)$ you can check that $\chi_{[0,\infty)}(A)\cdot A$ and $-\chi_{(-\infty,0)}(A)\cdot A$ (defined by the functional calculus) are Hilbert-Schmidt and both positive. Note that $A$ is the difference of these two operators.

Comment: @s.harp thank you so much. This was really helpfull.

Comment: Can you furthere elaborate why both of them are positive?

Comment: If $A$ is a normal operator, $f:\sigma(A)\to \Bbb C$ a measurable function then $f(A)$ has spectrum $\{f(\lambda)\mid \lambda\in \sigma(A)\}$. In particular $\chi_{[0,\infty)}(A)\cdot A$ and $-\chi_{(-\infty,0)}(A)\cdot A$ have spectrum $\subseteq [0,\infty)$ and $\subseteq (0,\infty)$ respectively.